# How to add variable in error message (php) multilanguage?

Tags: php, multilingual

Need error message in two languages, and have some trouble with single quotes...
This is how it looks like:

```
else if(trim($FullName) == '')
    $error = '<div class="errormsg">Please enter your Full Name!</div>';
}
```

And how when I put variable

```
else if(trim($FullName) == '')
    $error = '<div class="errormsg"><?php echo $lang['error']; ?></div>';
 }
```

So, when I put it like this, syntax becomes incorrect because single quotes..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did u try

```
else if(trim($FullName) == '')
    $error = '<div class="errormsg">'. $lang["error"] .'</div>';
 }
```

EDIT : echo is a php instruction that does not require you to re-open and re-close php tags (`<?php` and `?>`). You can compute strings thanks to concatenation which is some basic stuff in PHP

Comment: Then if there is no text, did you check if $lang["error"] does exist in your script ? You can check an array/object/var state by doing var_dump($var);

Comment: Re-open and re-close php tags, that was problem. Forgot about that.. Thank you!

Comment: No problem ! If this solves your problem, don't hesitate to check this as a useful answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I would use [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php), i.e.:

```
else if(empty(trim($FullName)))
    $error = '<div class="errormsg">Please enter your Full Name!</div>';
}
```

the following, doesn't make sense since you're inside a php block:

```
$error = '<div class="errormsg"><?php echo $lang['error']; ?></div>
```

Change for:

```
else if(empty(trim($FullName)))
    $error = '<div class="errormsg">'.$lang['error'].'</div>';
 }
```